# How to convert number to decimal string?

Tags: c++, c, ascii, hex

Hi everyone (newbie here),

I work on an embedded system and I need to convert hex number to an ASCII string.

Please read before answering to understand what I am asking for.

e.g. hexNumber = 0xFF
     ASCII = 0x32 0x35 0x35

The ASCII bytes are representation of the decimal value of the hexNumber. I.e 0xFF is 255, 0xFE will be 254, etc...

Essentially, each byte should generate 3 bytes for the decimal representation of the hex number.

The value is not entered using the keyboard, it is a value obtained from a smart card.

Comment: You can store the number as an int and then output each digit as a char = digit + '0'.

Comment: Should the result be 3 bytes for all values, i.e. should 0x3 give "003" or "3"?

Comment: 'hexNumber = 0xFF ASCII = 0x32 0x35 0x35' makes no sense

Comment: @DieterLücking: Those are the ASCII values for "255".

Comment: Store the hexNumber in a int. Print it to a string as a decimal value (use sprintf or a sstream). Loop over the characters (numbers) in the string and print them as a hex value?

Comment: Thank you so much. This community is the best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the C-style `sprintf()` for this:

```
char buf[4];
sprintf(buf, "%03d", 0xFF & (unsigned)byte_to_convert);
```

You can also use `snprintf()`, which is generally safer when the output format isn't fixed, but doesn't matter as much for this application.

If your embedded environment can't afford the cost of linking `printf` family functions from a library (they can be fairly large), then do the conversion with division and modulo, like so:

```
char buf[4];
buf[3] = 0;   /* NUL trminator */
buf[2] = (unsigned)byte_to_convert       % 10 + '0';
buf[1] = (unsigned)byte_to_convert / 10  % 10 + '0';
buf[0] = (unsigned)byte_to_convert / 100      + '0';
```

Comment: I like the simple buf[4] (there is no need for an expensive printf)

Answer (score 1):

Use `snprintf()` if you have it, or `sprintf()`.

Assuming the value is an integer variable, please realize that it's not a "hex value"; it's just a number in a variable. It's not stored in hex inside the computer's memory.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
int hexNumber = 0xFF;
int i;
char ss[4];

sprintf(ss,"%d",hexNumber);

printf("0x%x: ",hexNumber);

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("0x%x ",ss[i]);

printf("\n");
```

This will produce:

```
0xff: 0x32 0x35 0x35
```